# NEst RabbitMQ RPC nack doesn't reject the promise

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs, rpc

With nestJS rabbit MQ I use RPC from one server to another one. What I basically want is `await this.amqpConnection.request` to reject the promise when the consumer throw an error. As I understand from [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28817796/3872976)  and [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html#basic.nack) documentation when you **NACK** (negative ack) the message it should put the RPC response to a corresponding queue with an error information which would be passed to a client.  Here's some code example:

**Producer**

```js
import { AmqpConnection } from '@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq';

let amqpConnection: AmqpConnection;

sendMessage(payload: any) {
  try {
      const result = await this.amqpConnection.request({
        exchange: 'user',
        routingKey: 'test',
        queue: 'test',
        payload,
      });
      console.log(result);
  } catch (e) {
      console.error(e); // I expect this flow !!! 
  }
}
```

**Consumer**:

```js
  @RabbitRPC({
    exchange: 'user',
    routingKey: 'test',
    queue: 'test',
    errorBehavior: MessageHandlerErrorBehavior.NACK
  })
  public async rpcHandler(payload: any): Promise<any> {
     throw Error("Error text that should be proxied to console.error"):
  }
```

But the message doesn't even return to the client. Client gets rejected after a timeout, rather because of an error during consumer processing. If my understanding is not correct I would like to know if there's a builtin mechanism with nestjs to reject the message w/o manually creating some response types for an error and handling it on a client.

Answer (score 0):

You should throw exactly the `RpcException` from `@nestjs/microservices` and only with a certain argument

```
throw new RpcException({
   code: 42, // some number code
   message: 'wait. oh sh...', // some string value
});
```

Also if you using a custom exception filter then it should extends the `BaseRpcExceptionFilter` from `@nestjs/microservices`. Call the `getType()` method on an `ArgumentsHost` and if it's result equals to `'rpc'` then using the `super.catch` method.